# Oscillator built with react hooks won't stop

Tags: reactjs, audio, react-hooks, web-audio-api, javascript-oscillator

I'm trying to play around for the first time with the WebAudio API together with React.

My idea was to build a simple button that, once clicked, would start or stop a sound.

With the following code, I'm always getting the error "Failed to execute 'disconnect' on 'AudioNode': the given destination is not connected."

How can I fix it?
Thanks!

```
import { useState } from 'react';

function App() {
  const [ dataPlaying, setDataPlaying ] = useState(false) 

  const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext
  const audioContext = new AudioContext()

  let osc = audioContext.createOscillator()
    osc.type = 'sine'
    osc.frequency.value = 880

  const createOscillator = () => {
    if (dataPlaying === false) {
      osc.start()
      osc.connect(audioContext.destination)
      setDataPlaying(true)
    } else {
      osc.disconnect(audioContext.destination)
      setDataPlaying(false)
    }
  }
    
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button 
        onClick={() => createOscillator() }
        data-playing={ dataPlaying }>
        <span>Play/Pause</span>
      </button>  
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: My guess would be that on every render cycle you redefine/recreate a new audioContext and `osc` variable, so on a subsequent render when you click to stop it is a completely different object that hasn't been started. Have you tried using a ref to hold on to the context?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt to resolve the connection error.

1. Create the `AudioContext` external to the component.
2. Use an `useRef` hook to store an audio context to persist through rerenders.
3. Use an `useEffect` hook to instantiate an oscillator and manage audo context connection.
4. Use start/stop toggler to suspend or resume the context instead of connect/disconnect from it.

Updated Code

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;

export default function App() {
  const [dataPlaying, setDataPlaying] = useState(false);
  const audioContextRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const osc = audioContext.createOscillator();
    osc.type = "sine";
    osc.frequency.value = 880;

    // Connect and start
    osc.connect(audioContext.destination);
    osc.start();

    // Store context and start suspended
    audioContextRef.current = audioContext;
    audioContext.suspend();

    // Effect cleanup function to disconnect
    return () => osc.disconnect(audioContext.destination);
  }, []);

  const toggleOscillator = () => {
    if (dataPlaying) {
      audioContextRef.current.suspend();
    } else {
      audioContextRef.current.resume();
    }
    setDataPlaying((play) => !play);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={toggleOscillator} data-playing={dataPlaying}>
        <span>{dataPlaying ? "Pause" : "Play"}</span>
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit oscillator-built-with-react-hooks-wont-stop]

Comment: I don't understand what 


```// Store context and start suspended
audioContextRef.current = audioContext;
audioContext.suspend();
```
are for. 
I don't know if I should open another thread because I'm trying to build a range slider controlling the sound...but there are very few tutorials on react hooks + web audio api

Comment: @MarcoMazzai It stores the audio context in a mutable react ref that persists through rerenders. In your implementation you were redeclaring an audio context each render cycle, so when updating your `dataPlaying` state and later trying to stop the audio stream your code was attempting to operate on a different context.

Comment: I see. So if I have something like an input range to control the volume while the sound plays I should save the gain's value to a new ref?

Comment: @MarcoMazzai I think for this you would need to store the oscillator (`osc`) in a ref and set/update values for the oscillator there in a similar manner.

Comment: Thanks! It worked but with a ref applied to the gain..